# Cross-compiled glibc causing build errors

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile, glibc, google-chrome-os

I have built glibc 2.17 on Chrome OS after chrooting to Ubuntu(raring). Glibc had the `--with-headers` configure param specified to extracted Chrome OS kernel headers.

Then I installed the results into Chrome OS's `/usr/local` directory using `DESTDIR`. I also removed files conflicting with already present glibc, and symlinked the present ones into my new `/usr/local/` dir. It worked on i686 kernel, but now that I'm running x86_64(and rebuilt everything under that), this happens while trying to build openssl on Chrome OS:

```
    libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In function `dlfcn_globallookup':
    dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x11): warning: Using 'dlopen' in statically linked applications  requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
    /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/../lib64/libdl.a(dlopen.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `__dlopen' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
    /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    make[4]: *** [link_a.gnu] Error 1
```

I tried rebuilding binutils with `-fPIC`, but still no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error states that `libdl` needs to be recompiled with `-fPIC`. That's part of `libc`, not `binutils`, at least on XUbuntu 13.04

Comment: Recompiling glibc with `-fPIC` worked (actually, setting CFLAGS also requires you to set optimalization flags manually, so the final result was `CFLAGS=-fPIC -O2`. Thanks!